# Angular Interceptor Response 302

Tags: angular, interceptor, http-status-code-302

Can I make a interceptor to catch 302 response in angular, before automatic redirect?

How to intercept url redirect in angular response 302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should do something like below:**

1. Create a folder in src, ex: interceptors;
2. Create a file inside it, ex.: auth.ts;

**File content:**

Please see the comments.

```
 @Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 // Inject dependencies as you need
  constructor(private someService: someService, private route: Router) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        
    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap((resp) => {
        if (resp instanceof HttpResponse) {
          if (resp.status === 302) {
            // here you can implement your logic, or simply redirect as below
            this.route.navigate(['/someroute']);
          }
        }
      }),
       
      // You can also check for other errors as follows:
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errorMsg = err.error.message;

        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status == 401) {
            // here you can implement your logic, or simply redirect as below
            this.route.navigate(['/']);
            
          }
        }

        if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          console.log('Client side error caught in interceptor');
        } else {
          console.log('Server side error caught in interceptor');
        }
        return throwError(() => new Error(errorMsg));
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**In app.module.ts add the following:**

It means it will be available throughout the application.

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```